# Exception and logging

Tags: java, exception

I have one parent class "DownloadManagerWrapper.java" and I'm calling a method which is present in "DownloadManager.java". I want throw the exception and halt the program execution if there is an exception and the same time I want to log the error in log file using log4j.

I'm calling the `cacheUploadLog(intfcode,bankId)` method from `downloadDataCore()` method. So I feel I'm logging the same error to file in two places:

- from `cacheUploadLog()` method
- in `downloadDataCore()` after catch the exception which is thrown by `cacheUploadLog()` method.

Is it required to have `try` and `catch` block inside `downloadDataCore()` method?

Please provide your suggestion and help me to handle the exception and handling here.

### DownloadManagerWrapper.java

```
    public static void readInterfaceConfig(String intfCode, String bankId,String downloadId) {
        DownloadManager manager = new DownloadManager();
        manager.downloadDataFromCore(intfCodeFromDB, bankId, downloadId);
    }
```

### DownloadManager.java

```
    public String downloadDataFromCore(String intfcode, String bankId, String downloadId) throws DownloadCoreDataException {
        try
        {
            // here it contain some other code. formatting code, splitting, and other logic. may be  a chance there might exception arise here.                
            cacheUploadLog(intfcode, bankId);
            cacheDownloadConfig(intfcode, bankId);
        } catch (DownloadCoreDataException exception) {
            errorLogger.error("Error in downloaddatafromcore method", exception);
            throw new DownloadCoreDataException("Error in downloaddatafromcore method", exception);
        }
    }

    private void cacheUploadLog(String intfcode, String bankId) throws DownloadCoreDataException {
        try{
            String lastDownloadedTime = getLastDownloadedTime(intfcode, bankId);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            errorLogger.error("Error in getting primary_key from update_log table",exception);
            throw new DownloadCoreDataException("Error in getting primary_key " + 
                "from update_log table",exception);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you **want to log the parameter values for debugging purpose**, you can have a **try-catch** block inside `downloadDataFromCore` and log those parameter and just throw the exception. Otherwise it is not required as that method is already throwing the exception.

Comment: @Ravindra.downloadDataFromCore method will contain some other logic where exception may arise.in this case i need to go with try and catch inside downloadDataFromCore right? edited my question.

Comment: Right. However, you may want to catch some other exception which will be raised by the other piece of code. No need to specifically catch `DownloadCoreDataException` and throw it again.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to fix this:-

```
DownloadManager manager = new DownloadManager().downloadDataFromCore(intfCodeFromDB, bankId, downloadId);
```

This is the most weirdest call I've seen for a method, having a signature like this.

```
public String downloadDataFromCore(String intfcode, String bankId,
                            String downloadId)
```

Next, coming to your question. Since you want to both log the error and then for some reason, throw it again, you need to have that `try-catch` in the method. Else, its not a necessity, as the method already has the `throws` clause to throw the exception.

Comment: yes i will change the method signatore and call. i have edited my question.